# How to detect new position of video in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

So I am using the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package in my Flutter project and have made use of `VideoProgressIndicator` and it works exactly as intended:

```
Widget progBar(BuildContext context) {
  return VideoProgressIndicator(
    _controller,
    allowScrubbing: true, // user can touch/drag bar to change position of video.
    colors: VideoProgressColors(playedColor: Colors.red, bufferedColor: Colors.white),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6, horizontal: 9),
  );
}
```

**The issue:**

I have the timestamp(s) of the video as part of the player and when the user uses the `VideoProgressIndicator` to change the position of the video, I don't have the new position of the video so that I can update the timestamp(s).

**My question**:

How can I get the new position of the video when the `VideoProgressIndicator` changes it?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out my solution to be simply to create a custom progress bar that manipulates a timer.